# What are the events for Clicking Up or Down button on NumericUpDown called

Tags: c#, mouseclick-event, numericupdown

[image]

What are the events for Clicking Up or Down button on NumericUpDown called?

```
private void upNdownButtonNumeric_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int scale = Convert.ToInt32(numericScale.Value/100) * 100;
    mapComponent.ZoomTo(scale);

}
```

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.forms.numericupdown(v=vs.110).aspx   / there are no separate events for up and down. Use the click or valuechanged event.

Answer (score 0):

No events for click up and click down exist. Use event `ValueChanged`. Occurs when the Value property has been changed in some way.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.numericupdown%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ValueChanged` event. You are always able to understand inside the handler of that event what has been done - down or up.